# Shared Library on Mac OSX and QT

Tags: macos, qt, shared

Does anyone know how to get rid of this problem? I am using a Mac for developing for Maemo 5.

```
Killing remote process(es)...
Starting remote process...
Remote process started.
/opt/Blue/bin/Blue: error while loading shared libraries: libQtConnectivity.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Finished running remote process. Exit code was 127.
```

I have followed the instructions here:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Latest_Qt_and_Qt_mobility_evaluation_on_Maemo

I think I just need to make sure my mac links to that file, how to do that?

Building the package is fine but I get the error when I try to deploy it on my N900 phone.  The error appears in the QTCreator output.

Comment: That link on developer.nokia.com doesn't work.

Comment: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Latest_Qt_and_Qt_mobility_evaluation_on_Maemo